# Change field mask v-currency-field?

Tags: vue.js, currency, mask

Currently I use the element of v-currency-field, and what it does is put a mask of "0.00", if I start writing it is written from right to left, start the numbers after the decimal point, for example like this

0.00

0.01

0.12

1.23

I can place the cursor to place the number in another position, but the logic is the same. What do I need?

The link here is something similar to what I need https://kevinongko.github.io/vue-numeric/

I need the user to type from left to right, but can only write one decimal point and then two digits after the point

The link I put, what it does is change the format, for example

5555.55 You change the format to: 5,555.55 this is very good

But if the user says 5555.5555.555 if it is allowed, then change the value to 5555.56

This is something I do not want, I need that from the beginning it is limited to only one point and then 2 digits

Any way to do it?

I'd be really grateful

Regards!

Comment: I have the same problem with the v-money library. 
I think it will be better to modify the v-model in order to better show the mask